# Any tool to decide which color to use?

Tags: color

This might sound like a soft question. Generally, I am very poor in colors' names and coloring things. Since there are plenty of choices of the form `color1!percentage!color2`, I was wondering if there exists a tool or website that shows xcolor palette where the user chooses a color and it gives him/her the corresponding `color1!percentage!color2` form. Does such tool exist?

Comment: Tools usually show you the RGB values. You can use them as well.

Comment: @Users, it's only 10 mins, please stop close vote.

Comment: Maybe this website would help: http://www.colorhexa.com/  It provides extensive help at formulating and discerning colors, in terms of their makeup constituents.  Just click on the red-circle dot in the search bar to get started.  The site is actually quite amazing in its helpfulness.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation of `xcolor` has a palette of different systems of names, pp. 38-40: `dvipsnames` (68 colours), `svgnames` (more or less   HTML palette, 151 colours), `x11names` (317 colours).

There's also an extensive document, `chroma`, available in MiKTeX, but not TeX Live. Under TeX Live, you'll have to install it in your `texmflocal` from [CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/chroma). Colours are classified by names, and by parameters, according to the models `rgb`, `cmy` and `hsb`